# Please correct my code Python

Tags: python

I am trying to read from a file and return solutions based on the problem that the user inputs. I have saved the text file in the same location, that is not an issue. At the moment, the program just crashes when I run it and type a problem eg "screen".

Code

```
    file = open("solutions.txt", 'r')
    advice = []
    read = file.readlines()
    file.close()
    print (read)
    for i in file:
        indword = i.strip()
        advice.append (indword)

    lst = ("screen","unresponsive","frozen","audio")
    favcol = input("What is your problem? ")
    probs = []
    for col in lst:
        if col in lst:
            probs.append(col)

    for line in probs:
        for solution in advice:
            if line in solution:
                print(solution)
```

The text file called "solutions.txt" holds the following info:

screen: Take the phone to a repair shop where they can replace the damaged screen.

unresponsive: Try to restart the phone by holding the power button for at least 4 seconds.

frozen: Try to restart the phone by holding the power button for at least 4 seconds.

audio: If the audio or sound doesnt work, go to the nearest repair shop to fix it.

Comment: `for col in lst: if col in lst:` what do you intend this to do? What do you mean by "crashes"? You should provide the specific error.

Comment: Now I have worked on it a bit, the code works however, When I input "screen" It prints out the whole text file, not the certain line I want it to print, "screen:..." , any ideas?

Comment: There are numerous problems with the code and simpler ways to perform this task. The accepted answer does not address these. If you remove the accepted tag on the incorrect answer then I will illustrate a simpler way

Comment: @roganjosh I have removed the accepted tag on the incorrect answer.

Comment: I posted an answer regardless. You're free to choose whether or not it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your question reminds me a lot of my learning, so I will try give an answer to expand on your learning with lots of `print` statements to consider how it works carefully. It's not the most efficient or stable approach but hopefully of some use to you to move forwards.

```
print "LOADING RAW DATA"

solution_dictionary = {}

with open('solutions.txt', 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        dict_key, solution = line.split(':')
        print "Dictionary 'key' is: ", dict_key
        print "Corresponding solution is: ", solution
        solution_dictionary[dict_key] = solution.strip('\n')

print '\n'
print 'Final dictionary is:', '\n'
print solution_dictionary
print '\n'
print 'FINISHED LOADING RAW DATA'


solved = False
while not solved: # Will keep looping as long as solved == False

    issue = raw_input('What is your problem? ')
    solution = solution_dictionary.get(issue)

    """ If we can find the 'issue' in the dictionary then 'solution' will have
    some kind of value (considered 'True'), otherwise 'None' is returned which 
    is considered 'False'."""

    if solution: 
        print solution
        solved = True

    else:
        print ("Sorry, no answer found. Valid issues are 'frozen', " 
                "'screen' 'audio' or 'unresponsive'")
        want_to_exit = raw_input('Want to exit? Y or N? ')

        if want_to_exit == 'Y':
            solved = True

        else:
            pass
```

Other points:
- don't use 'file' as a variable name anywhere. It's a python built-in and can cause some weird behaviour that you'll struggle to debug https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html 
- If you get an error, don't say "crashes", you should provide some form of traceback e.g.:

```
a = "hello" + 2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-6f5e94f8cf44> in <module>()
----> 1 a = "hello" + 2

TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

- your question title will get you down-votes unless you are specific about the problem. "help me do something" is unlikely to get a positive response because the error is ambiguous, there's no sign of Googling the errors (and why the results didn't work) and it's unlikely to be of any help to anyone else in the future.

Best of luck :)

Answer (score 0):

When I change the line "for i in file:" to "for i in read:" everything works well.

Comment: When I change that and run the code, I typed in "screen" when prompted, but the WHOLE text file is printed, and I only want the specific line which has the corresponding solution "screen:" to be printed. Any ideas?

Comment: @SarahLivingstone Please don't mark an answer correct (green tick) if it does not solve the problem. This will harm your chances for help too as people will not open the question.

Answer (score 0):

To output only the line starting with "screen" just forget the probs variable and change the last for statement to

```py
for line in advice:
    if line.startswith( favcol )  :
        print line
        break
```

For the `startswith()` function refer to https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith

And: the advices of roganjosh are helpfull. Particularly the one "please don't use python keywords (e.g. file) as variable names". I spent hours of debugging with some bugs like "file = ..." or "dict = ...".